# Record selection conditional formula

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm making a conditional formula in Crystal Reports for the record selection. The value of `{IDENTITY_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_TYPE}` can be either 1 (Present Street Address) or 3 (Present Mailing Address).

There will always be a Street Address (1) but I would prefer to use the Mailing Address (3) if one exists. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: please include a visual (image) of the issue and expected result

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to write a custom SQL statement inside Crystal to handle this. Since custom-tooled SQL tables evaluate before the report is even reached, it will do the record selection for you.

I can't see your tables so you'll have to write the logic yourself. But the gist is that you'll want to return a new field, let's call it `PreferredAddress` which will be a varChar that will:

1. Check to see if a Present Mailing Address (3) is on file for this record
2. If yes, return the Present Mailing Address (3) as `PreferredAddress`
3. If no, return the Present Street Address (1) as `PreferredAddress`

Answer (score 0):

```
if {IDENTITY_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_TYPE} = Present Mailing Address
```

then true,
else 
 {IDENTITY_ADDRESS.ADDRESS_TYPE} = Present Street Address